# I am trying to make apk file.I have eclipse with sdk installed and jdk. i try to build with this command "cordova build" then I get this error.

Tags: android, asp.net

```
C:\Hello\hello>cordova build
```

ANDROID_HOME=E:\MCA\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Observed package id 'build-tools;18.1.0' in inconsistent location 'E:\MCA\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\build-tools\android-4.3' (Expected 'E:\MCA\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\build-tools\18.1.0')
Observed package id 'system-images;android-18;default;armeabi-v7a' in inconsistent location 'E:\MCA\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\system-images\android-18\armeabi-v7a' (Expected 'E:\MCA\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\system-images\android-18\default\armeabi-v7a')

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 25].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.928 secs

Comment: How did you update your Android SDK?

Comment: in cmd apply command "android"  then open SDK Manager , and in this i update.

Comment: Try removing SDK 25 packages and install again, accepting all terms and conditions.

Comment: ok I wiil try ...